# Intuition for Root Test.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found a lot on the ratio test, and intuitively how or what are we basically doing but I can't seem to find anything on Root Test. Hence this question.

The Root Test given in my university textbook is as follows :

Let $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = L$

- If $L <1$ then the series is convergent.
- If $L>1$ then the series is divergent.
- If $L=1$ then the test fails.

Again, I'm not looking for a proof. I'm looking for an intuitive explanation for the Root Test. Also I decided to write down the definition that is given in my textbook here because there are slightly different definitions out there and some of them use notations I'm not aware of. So yea, I'd appreciate if someone could just explain this in simple English. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The idea is quite simple : if 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = L$$ that means that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} $ is almost equal to $L$ when $n$ is large. So $|a_n|$ is almost equal to $L^n$ when $n$ is large. Now it is just a comparison with a geometric series, of which you know the behavior (with the different cases $L > 1$, $L=1$ and $L<1$).

Comment: Okay, for L<1 the series would then be absolutely convergent hence our original series will be convergent. I get it, cool. But for L> 1 that logic would tell me that series is absolutely divergent, which doesn't imply that the original series would be divergent too. So how would explain the divergent condition using that same logic? Especially when $a_n <0$ for some $n$?

Comment: If $L>1$, $L^n$ does not tend to $0$... So $|a_n|$ does not tend to $0$, so $a_n$ does not tend to $0$, so the series is divergent.

Comment: If $a_n$ doesn't tend to $0$ then how can you conclude it's divergent? Shouldn't the correct conclusion be that it's "NOT" convergent as $\sum a_n$ need not necessarily be a series of positive terms?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... "Divergent" means "not convergent".

Comment: I'm almost certain that's not the case. Only when you have series of positive terms, the sequence of partial sums is a monotonic increasing sequence, in which case, it can be either of the two — convergent, if bounded above, divergent (sequence of partial sums tends to $∞$) if not bounded above. This is not case with a series in general. The sequence of partial sums can be an oscillating sequence as well.

Comment: Well it depends of the definition then. But for the large majority of mathematicians all around the world, "divergent" means "not convergent". Even if it is oscillating, it is considered to be divergent.

Comment: By the way, your textbook means obviously "not convergent" when it says divergent. Otherwise, consider the sequence $a_n = (-2)^n$ : it satisfies $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \rightarrow 2$, but what would you say ? That the series is not divergent ?

Comment: Using geometric series is a good intuition but it does not show why L = 1 is inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

$\color{#E82}{\sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}}$ tells us the value of the number needed to multiply by itself $\color{limegreen}n$ times to reach $\color{#59F}{|a_n|}$. We can multiply $\color{#E82}{\text{the value of the number needed to multiply by themselves}}$ $\color{limegreen}n$ $\color{orange}{\text{times to reach $\color{#59F}{|a_n|}$}}$ by themselves $\color{limegreen}n$ times to get $\left( \sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}\right)^{\color{limegreen}n}$. Then, by taking the sum, we get $\sum \left( \sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}\right)^{\color{limegreen}n}$, which is equivalent to $\sum {\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}$. For example: $$\sum_{n=1}^∞ n \text{ can be represented as } \sum_{n=1}^∞(n^\frac1n)^n \text{ or } 1 +\sqrt2^2+\sqrt[3]{3}^3..., \text{separating a number into what needs to be multiplied some times to get the number, already multiplied by themselves some times}$$

Assume that $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}\color{#E82}{\sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}} < 1$. This means that after $\mathrm{\color{palevioletred}{a\space certain\space point}}$, $\color{#E82}{\sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}}$ stays under $1$, which means there's a number between $\color{#E82}{\sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}}$ and $1$, something like $0.9999$ (or greater). However, the series
$$\sum_{n=\mathrm{\color{palevioletred}{a\space certain\space point} + 1}}^∞(0.9999)^n$$ is a geometric series with $r<1$, so this series converges. Because $\sum \left( \sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}\right)^{\color{limegreen}n}$ is a finite sum to  $\mathrm{\color{palevioletred}{a\space certain\space point}}$ and always less than $0.9999^n$ after that, the series is less than the sum of $2$ finite sums and greater or equal to zero (Because we are taking the absolute value sum).

If $\lim \limits_{n \to ∞}\color{#E82}{\sqrt[\color{limegreen}n]{\color{#59F}{|a_n|}}}$ is greater than zero, then we will eventually be summing up numbers greater than $1$. (For example, $(1.0001)^n$ is greater than $1$)